# Add icons as buttons in html

Tags: html

Add icons as buttons in html. for example, Add as plus icon and delete as minus icon. For below ex, I need to see plus icon on teh screen rather than Add. Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add an icon library, such as font awesome, and append icons to HTML buttons**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Add icon library -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
    .btn {
      background-color: DodgerBlue;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    /* Darker background on mouse-over */
    
    .btn:hover {
      background-color: RoyalBlue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
  <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>

</body>

</html>
```

---

*for more information- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_icon_buttons.asp*